# Hibernate not retrieving correct row given a date from MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria

I have a `Spring MVC` project and a `MySQL` Database which has a table with the following rows:

[image]

I have a function that gets row by the date `field`:

```
@Override
public List listAllTimeSheetDetailsByDate(LocalDate date) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = getSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<TimeSheetDetails> cr = cb.createQuery(TimeSheetDetails.class);
    Root<TimeSheetDetails> root = cr.from(TimeSheetDetails.class);
    cr.select(root).where(cb.equal(root.get("date"), date));
    Query<TimeSheetDetails> query = getSession().createQuery(cr);
    List<TimeSheetDetails> results = query.getResultList();
    return results;
}
```

I am using Hibernate's `getCriteriaBuilder()` and `createQuery()` implementations.

The problem is that when I want to retrieve the row with date `2018-11-03` I get back the row which corresponds to the date `2018-11-02`. I am using `LocalDate`, so the days of the month do not start at `0`. Here is `Hibernate's Log`:

```
INFO    [default task-4] stdout  - Hibernate: select timesheetd0_.timeSheetDetailsId as timeShee1_2_, timesheetd0_.date as date2_2_, timesheetd0_.employeeId as employee3_2_, timesheetd0_.endTime as endTime4_2_, timesheetd0_.startTime as startTim5_2_ from TimeSheetDetails timesheetd0_ where timesheetd0_.date=?
**TRACE   [default task-4] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [1] as [DATE] - [2018-11-03]**
TRACE   [default task-4] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor  - extracted value ([timeShee1_2_] : [INTEGER]) - [4]
**TRACE   [default task-4] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor  - extracted value ([date2_2_] : [DATE]) - [2018-11-02]**
TRACE   [default task-4] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor  - extracted value ([employee3_2_] : [VARCHAR]) - [3]
TRACE   [default task-4] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor  - extracted value ([endTime4_2_] : [TIME]) - [05:00]
TRACE   [default task-4] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor  - extracted value ([startTim5_2_] : [TIME]) - [01:00]
```

I do not understand why its getting the previous date. Furthermore, when I want to retrieve the `"2018-11-30"` date, I get back an empty set. I do not understand why this is occurring.

Comment: Have you tried to change the system timezone?

Comment: No, I do not think. How would I do that?

Comment: Change it in your system, where the application is run.